# Compilation error while running a spring boot application

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application which is not running in intellj and even if this application runs in eclipse I always have to move the "Jre library" in the build path up to the top and then run mvn install.

The entire code can be found at - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/SpringCaching.git

Can anyone please help in what is the issue.

Error :-

```
INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[6,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[7,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[8,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[9,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[10,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[16,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[17,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RequestMapping
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/service/impl/ContactServiceImpl.java:[15,31] error: package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[6,31] error: package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[11,9] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ApiError
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[22,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ApiError
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[27,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ApiError
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[34,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ApiError
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[25,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[31,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[30,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[36,26] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[35,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[40,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[47,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[46,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[52,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[51,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[57,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[56,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[62,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class ContactController
/Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[61,2] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 27 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.233 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-21T19:11:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/299M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project SpringCaching: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[6,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[7,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[8,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[9,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[10,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[16,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[17,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RequestMapping
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/service/impl/ContactServiceImpl.java:[15,31] error: package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[6,31] error: package org.springframework.http does not exist
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[11,9] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ApiError
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[22,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ApiError
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[27,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ApiError
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/exception/ApiError.java:[34,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ApiError
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[25,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[31,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[30,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[36,26] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[35,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[40,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[47,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[46,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[52,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[51,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[57,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[56,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[62,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class ContactController
[ERROR] /Git Code/SpringCaching/src/main/java/com/myapp/controller/ContactController.java:[61,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This error happens when I run mvn clean and then man install.

Comment: What exactly does "not running in intellij" mean? Does it compile? If not, what's the compilation error? If it compiles but something fails whn you run `SpringDemoAppApplication` then can you describe **what** that failure is? Do you have a stacktrace? Does this application build and run from the command line?

Comment: @glitch : Error added in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring-boot-starter-web dependency in your pom.xml has scope=test but you have non test code using classes provided by that artifact so just remove the scope element from that dependency then the 'web' classes will be available in your 'main' source tree.